# finding the unpaired integer with O(logN)

Tags: javascript, performance

I stumbled upon this quiz:

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.
>   The array contains an odd number of elements, and each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired.
>   E.G
>     A = [9,3,9,3,5,7,5 ] // 3, 5 and 9 can be paired while 7 is left alone
>   Write a efficient function that given an array A of N integers returns the value of the unpaired element.
>   Note:
>   1) N is an odd integer within the range [1..1,000,000];
>   2) each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000];
>   3) all but one of the values in A occur an even number of times.

here's my solution, which is not considered efficient because it's complexity is O(N**2).

```
function solution(A) {
    let res;
    A.sort();
    //3,3,7,9,9,9,9    
    while(A.length>1) {
        if(A[0] === A[1]) {
            A.shift();
            A.shift();
        } else {
            res = A[0];
            break;
        }
    }
    res = A.length === 1 ? A[0] : res;
    return res;
}
```

How do i improve this from here?

Here the failing tests:
[image: failing test img]

Comment: `O(N^2)` is bad code, but where are you getting your `O(logn)` requirement from? It's not part of the quoted text, and it makes no sense either. The correct solution is `O(NlogN)` which can be trivially achieved with a sort and linear search.

Comment: Which by the way is what you did, your solution is `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was stating `O(logN)` in this test or another, but for sure it says `efficient` , and i'm failing the few performance test :(

Comment: Note the "trivially" in my first sentence. You can write a better algorithm by not sorting, but instead as you parse your array once from left to write you use a `Set` to check if the element you're parsing exists, if it does you found a pairing (remove from set), if not then you just add it. At the end print the contents of the set, that's your loners.

Comment: It worked in no time. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already saw this problem, you can XOR all numbers in an array and the final result will be the only number not paired.
This solution is quite fast and should satisfy your speed requirement,

Small basic example:

> console.log(12 ^ 3 ^ 3 ^ 12 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 4)

The above code will return 5 (which is the only number with no pair on my example).

Comment: WOW, that's some low level programming wizardy. How could you even think something like that.
It totally makes sense after you see it but there's literally no way i'd think that in a bilion year

Comment: That is exactly what I thought :D , but yeah it works !

Answer (score 1):

thanks [@Bindy1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108796/blindy)

here's the code i wrote based on your suggestion.

```
function solution(A) {
    let mySet = new Set();
    let auxFn;
    A.forEach( item => {
        auxFn = mySet.has(item) ? 'delete' : 'add';
        mySet[auxFn](item);
    });
    return [...mySet][0];
}
```

[image: image result]

Comment: Yeah I definitely couldn't have written that code in JS, I don't even know what that return argument means. Was either describe the algorithm or write it out in C# lol

Comment: If u wanna write it in C I'll set the answer as correct. The goal was to find an optimization more than the code in a given language.
Btw, that return  "unpack" the set in different values `...mySet`, box them in an array `[]`, and take the one at pos 0  `[0]`

Comment: Mark that other answer as correct, the XOR trick is the true solution to this problem :)